# How to fill a column based on first column

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, phpmyadmin

I am making a mySQL table which lists ~70 products and information on whether they are compatible or not. For the sake of simplifying the question, I will pretend there were only four products.

```
Product1    Product2    Compatible?
A           A           Yes
A           B           No
A           C           Maybe
A           D           Yes
B           A           Yes
B           B           Yes
B           C           Yes
B           D           No
C           A           Yes
C           B           Maybe
C           C           Yes
C           D           Yes
D           A           Yes
D           B           No
D           C           Yes
D           D           Yes
```

If I already have a table like (every product is obviously compatible with itself)

```
Product1    Product2    Compatible?
A           A           Yes
B           B           Yes
C           C           Yes
D           D           Yes
```

Is there a way I can quickly fill out the first two columns so they follow the correct pattern? (so I dont have to be doing it manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use nested loops:  If you know how many products you have, lets call it n products.

2^n total rows will be in your table.  Additionally, product 1 will have each inventory item n times.  (In your example 4 items, so 2^4 = 16 total rows and each item occurs in product1 column n=4 times.

Thus a nested loop can be achieved to do the insert...

```
$inventory = array(A, B, C, D); 
for(i=0;i<2^n;i++){
   for(j=0; j<n; j++){
       //insert Column1=$inventory[i], Column2=$inventory[j];
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant n^2. (if there are 70 products, there would be 70 rows per product; 70*70)

But thanks, I didn't consider trying a for loop.

Comment: Sorry about that, I may be mistaken but glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

[Insert-After triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)!

And when inserting with phpMyadmin leave the column blank. let the trigger fill last column.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into compatibleProducts
select distinct p1.ProductID, p2.ProductID, 'Maybe'
from productTable p1
join productTable p2 on p1.ProductID <> p2.ProductID
```

I assumed that you already have them compatible with themselves, based on your second list.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to have to dumb it down a bit more for me.

The p1.ProductID and p2.ProductID. I will assume those are the first and second columns. But then what are p1 and p2 (alone)?

Comment: The idea is that you join the product table to itself.  p1 and p2 are aliases, in order to refer to each side of the join individually.  The join condition is that the products are different.  This simple query would give you the desired 70*70 rowset, if modified with the right table/column names.